# Cannot Start or Delete Azure Recovery Plan

Tags: azure

I have a Recovery Plan in Azure Site Recovery. On Jun 29, the Test Failover on the recovery plan finishes successfully.

However, when I try to start the Test Failover on July 7 (no changes have been made to my Azure account), it immediately fails, with the error "Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.".  I checked Recovery Job, there is no job created there

When I try deleting the Recovery Plan, it failed at once with error msg "Could not delete recovery plan 'XXXXXX' because an action is in progress. Verify that no actions are pending.

I checked everywhere in the Azure Management Portal. There is no running or pending jobs.

Could you help me identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, looks like some ajax calls have missed causing this mess behind the scenes.Try creating a recovery plan again, if not your best bet might be to raise a support ticket and sort it out.